# Why getNumPartitions() returns different values for the same dataset?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, partitioning

I have one main dataset. I need to apply some filtering and augmentation methods that require some `groupby` and `joins` on this dataset.

When I run `df.rdd.getNumPartitions()` after finalizing the process , I get 40. However If I write the same processed final file into the database and reread, and rerun `df.rdd.getNumPartitions()` again, I get 18 partition size.

I'm trying to understand how the  `getNumPartitions` works. What is the reason of this change?

Why `getNumPartitions` returns a different value after writing it somewhere and rerading?